# OWIN WebApp.Start gives A first chance exception of type 'System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException' occurred in mscorlib.dll

Tags: .net, owin

In my code i have this:

> ```
>         HOST = "*";
>         PORT = 9000;
> ```

```
        baseAddress = "http://" + HOST + ":" + PORT + "/";

        // Start OWIN host. Should be called in TT extension code
        WebApp.Start<Startup>(url: baseAddress);
```

which is leading to:

A first chance exception of type 'System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException' occurred in mscorlib.dll
An unhandled exception of type 'System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException' occurred in mscorlib.dll
Additional information: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation.

Online I have found a possible solution by typing in CMD run  as Admin:

> `netsh http add urlacl url=http://+:9000/ user=Everyone`

but this has not resolved the issue. Can anyone help?

Comment: What is the inner exception?

Comment: Access is Denied from System.Collections.NetListnerException

Comment: One solution is to run as Administrator but is there a way to allow  the system to work with users instead.

Comment: Hello @azuric did you manage to resolve your problem?

Comment: As I posted above the only way I managed to solve this was by running everything as an administrator instead of the user.

Comment: I cant fix this issue with any of the suggested issue, I still get it when I run it as administrator.

Comment: Changing the host to "localhost" instead of "*" fixed it for me.  Obviously this means it won't accept external connections.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You simply run in an elevated cmd:

```
netsh http add urlacl url=http://*:9000/ user=your_user_name
```

Please note, that you mentioned using a **star** and not the **plus** sign. So you have to add a star route to your urlacl and not a plus route as mentioned in your post. After this, you don't have to start it as Admin.

Answer (score 0):

The `urlacl` suggestions above didn't help me.  I was getting this exception when trying to use port 5000 (in later testing, port 9000 did ***not*** cause this exception for me). Changing to port 12345 (as suggested in the readme.txt after I ran `Install-Package Microsoft.Owin.SelfHost -Pre` in Package Manager Console) was my fix.